# How can I count paragraphs of my XML file and display them on the HTML file using XSLT?

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

Basically I have a text containing a couple of paragraphs, which have to be counted. The paragraph number then has to be displayed left of the paragraph.

I successfully counted all paragraphs using the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//troonrede">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(paragraph)"/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, I do not know how to implement this to my HTML output. Sorry, started using XSLT today and I could not find this solution anywhere else.

Kind regards,

Thijmen.

Edit: XML sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>
<!DOCTYPE troonrede
  [ <!ENTITY euml "ë"> ]
>
<troonrede spreker="Koningin Beatrix">
    <hoofd>
        Leden van de <organisatie>Staten-Generaal</organisatie>
    </hoofd>
    <paragraph>
        Willen wij daadkrachtig het economisch herstel vorm kunnen geven, dan is stabiel bestuur gewenst. 
        Intensief wordt sinds de <organisatie> Tweede Kamer</organisatie>-verkiezingen van <datum>9 juni</datum> 
        gewerkt aan de totstandkoming van een nieuw kabinet. Lopende de kabinetsformatie past het huidige kabinet
        terughoudendheid bij het doen van beleidsvoorstellen voor het komende jaar. 
        </paragraph>
    <paragraph> 
        Lange tijd en wereldwijd zullen de gevolgen van de financieel-economische crisis voelbaar blijven. 
        Een ingrijpend pakket van ombuigingen is nu noodzakelijk om de positie van ons land ook op de lange 
        termijn te verbeteren. Maatregelen voor de jaren na <datum>2011</datum> zullen vanzelfsprekend door 
        een nieuw kabinet voorbereid moeten worden.
        </paragraph>
</troonrede>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal XML input sample and the corresponding HTML you want to create, to explain the problem. If you want to number items, then, given that the target format is HTML, you could consider using an ordered list `ol`. Or as an alternative, in XSLT there is `xsl:number` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#numbering-based-on-position

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you. I'll look into the ordered list. XML sample is added to my original post.

Comment: So which elements are the paragraphs? You wrote that `count(paragraph)` counts them successfully but I don't see any such element in the input XML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen sorry, I forgot to translate. Should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained which HTML format you want to use to represent your document but as you want to number the paragraphs you could transform them into an HTML ordered list `ol` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="troonrede">
      <section>
          <h2>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="hoofd"/>
          </h2>
          <ol>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="paragraph"/>
          </ol>
      </section>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
      <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kk/2

Comment: Thank you a lot! There is one problem left though; I see the indent of the list, however, I do not see any number. It's white (just as the background). Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Where don't you see any numbers, which tool do you use to view the transformation result? I can't imagine a browser not rendering item numbers for ordered lists.

Comment: I use Safari to view the rendered HTML file. Neither Firefox or Chrome render it. Should I post my code?

Comment: I have one adjustment as the HTML body element somehow was not created in the earlier suggestion. If that doesn't improve the rendering then, yes, please edit your question and show us minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and HTML result, together with an explanation on you feed it to Safari (e.g. using client-side XSLT?).